# Express server loads html page with/without css/js when last route character is without/with '/', respectively

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

The following is affecting my second html page *model.html*:
If my route address is with a '/ at the end (typed on browser addr field) like so: *http://localhost:3002/home/model/* then the correct html page is loaded, but no css/js is loaded.

If my route address is without a '/ at the end like so: *http://localhost:3002/home/model* then the correct html page is loaded, and css/js is loaded.

Without '/' at the end, css/js loads fine using *statics/css/style.css* and *js/dynamicData.js*

The weird part is that when '/' is at the end, I can use *../statics/css/style.css* to load the css and *"../js/chartData.js"* to load js - but that means the one without '/' now longer loads the css/js.

```
My folder structure:
    js - has other js scripts
    node_modules
    statics
      css - has style.css
      image - has images
      index.html
      model.html
    index.js - init express server
    pc_server.js - express server
```

Express code (pc_server.js)

Middleware setup?:

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
// base = '/home'
app.use(base, express.static(__dirname));
```

Routes:

```
const INDEX_PAGE = '/';
const MODEL_PAGE = '/home/model';

function setupRoutes(app) {

  const BASE = app.locals.base;

  app.get(INDEX_PAGE, redirectHome(app));

  // BASE = '/home'
  app.get(BASE, toHomePage(app));
  app.get(MODEL_PAGE, toModelPage(app));
```

Routes functions defined:

```
function redirectHome(app) {
  return errorWrap(async function(req, res) {
    try {
      res.redirect(app.locals.base);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
}

function toHomePage(app) {
  return errorWrap(async function(req, res) {
    try {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/statics/index.html'));
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
}

function toModelPage(app) {
  return errorWrap(async function(req, res) {
    try {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/statics/model.html'));
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
}
```

The goal is to load the same page with css/js with either *http://localhost:3002/home/model/* or *http://localhost:3002/home/model*

Additional: Why is it that when I type *http://localhost:3002/home* I get *http://localhost:3002/home/* automatically on my browser addr field?

Comment: when opening developers console (f12), it shows 404 errors for 'http://localhost:3002/home/model/css/style.css'?

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3002/home/model/statics/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
GET http://localhost:3002/home/model/statics/image/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
2localhost/:27 GET http://localhost:3002/home/model/js/chartData.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## the problem

it probably occurs due to relative links in your site.

- when `home/model` is used - relative `css/style.css` link will lead to `home/css/style.css`
- when `home/model/` is used, the same link will lead to `home/model/css/style.css`

## the solution:

the easiest way to solve it is changing your link tag to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../home/statics/css/style.css">
```

this link goes to the root address, and then enters your path Independently from the user's path.

## why it's working?

the `../../` prefix tell the browser to go two levels up.

the browser consider the "home/model/" as a visit inside a model folder inside home folder. two levels upward lead the browser to the root level, where it has a clean start.
when the user visits "home/model", it considered as a file inside the home folder. one level upward is the root level, and the second `../` does nothing.

after achieving the root level - the browser entering "home/statics/css/style.css" and find the right file in both cases :)

Comment: Looked at the dev console when on /home/model/ page and I see it's trying to get files via localhost:3002/home/model/statics/css/style.css. I don't have a model dir where dirs like statics and js exist. So I created a model dir and copied the js and statics folder into it - this seems to work (all css/js files load). But, it's such a wacky solution, any cleaner solution?

Comment: have you tried to change the link tag inside the html script?

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggested href but the css does not loads for either case. It seems that with no '/', the address it starts looking for statics/css/styel.css is /home/ but with '/' it starts looking with /home/model/

Comment: maybe try `../../home/statics/css/style.css`, to go two levels up before entering the back to the home folder

Comment: YES, that really did the trick. Thanks so much! Explanation as to why this works?

Comment: nice to hear that ! I've added some explanations, hope now that now Its clear